# Create fake drag event to move ViewPager around

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with `Fragment`s in it. I want to programmatically create a motion event to 'peek' at the `Fragment`s left and right to the current `Fragment` in the `ViewPager` (showing part of the adjacent Fragments, then moving back to the current `Fragment`). It should look like a user was doing this.

I tried `ViewPager.fakeDragBy` but this happens instantly and is too fast. 
I had a look at `MotionEvent.obtain()` and `View.dispatchTouchEvent`, this seems the way to go to do this, right?

On which `View` do i have to dispatch the `MotionEvents` on? 
And do I have to manually dispatch several `MotionEvent`s to achieve what I want, e.g. `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_???`, `ACTION_UP`?

**EDIT**:

I tried the following:

```
public void drag(View view, float fromX, float toX, float fromY,
                 float toY, int stepCount) {

    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    float y = fromY;
    float x = fromX;

    float yStep = (toY - fromY) / stepCount;
    float xStep = (toX - fromX) / stepCount;

    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);

    view.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    for (int i = 0; i < stepCount; ++i) {

        y += yStep;
        x += xStep;
        eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, x, y, 0);
        view.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    }

    eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
    view.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

}
```

Which creates a drag motion just fine, problem is: it is very fast. I tried `Thread.sleep()` inside the loop and playing around with the eventTime (adding some time to it on every iteration within the for-loop), to no avail: the touch events are dispatched delayed, but the actual reaction of the `ViewPager` still happens very fast.

Comment: no. you need fakeDragBy called several times,  the best job for a Handler for example

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really work. It should look like a user would slowly do the motion.

Comment: Have you tried my implementation?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25476109/2158970

Comment: @Yuraj Yeah, it works quite well. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
if (!viewpager.isFakeDragging()) {
    viewpager.beginFakeDrag();
}
viewpager.fakeDragBy(value);
```

Documentation: 
[fakeDragBy(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#fakeDragBy(float)), 
[beginFakeDrag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#beginFakeDrag()), 
[endFakeDrag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#endFakeDrag()).

and in `onAnimationEnd()`

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator mAnimation) {
    viewpager.endFakeDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st way**:

Use `OverScroller` object with `LinearInterpolator` and set a duration duration (from x1 to x2 in 300ms maybe)

call `computeScrollOffset()` inside your for loop to find current position and break the loop when  `isFinished()` returns true.

---

**2nd way**

Use Object animator with custom property and use your fakeDrag method in it and run it like a common animation.