# Bounce ViewPaage From the End

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

I am working on a Android app in which i am using View Pager . I need to bounce page from the end position of viewpager same as IOS home page drawer .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I need $100k, could you show what you have tried?

Comment: Hello Nikola 'Sorry', but can you give me free help if possible . I will take paid help soon as i will have money to give you .

Comment: No, that wasn't the point. I was trying to say, that you need to show what you have tried and avoid looking for complete implementation. This is free of charge community and works solely on the will of the contributors.

Comment: can you add me sachin.auxiliumit skype or give me your skype id .

Comment: i have used this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475882/android-viewpager-bounce-to-half-a-page but this is not working for me . as saying again and again no beginFakeDrag is called

Comment: i can pass code to you on skype